# How to get Gmail Email address from user logged in Salesforce with Formula

Tags: email, formula, formula-field

What i am trying to accomplish if is possible is I want to get the email address from a user logged in Salesforce.

How this should work. I have User that is Manager in Salesforce. On that user 5 people can log in in different timing. Most of them do edits and changes and all of them have different Gmail email addresses.
What I want to accomplish here is whenever they make edit/create a lead/account/opportunity or contact, a formula field should get their Gmail address and write it in that field.

Can someone help me out with this it will solve quite a lot of problems.

Comment: Shared user accounts are against the MSA. While I've never heard anyone getting hit with that rule, trying to address this publicly might not be the best approach.

Comment: I thought that was a no no.. esp in your case.  Developers here use the same account sometimes, but for your case It may not be wise to do this.

Comment: It's not about development or publicly speaking. All i want to accomplish is whenever some of those 5 people log in into that specific manager and if they do edits. I will know which one made those edits by getting that email address from them. This way i will have a good track of who is doing what.

Additionally I've spoken with SF support and my account manager regarding this case. They didn't had problem with that so I don't see why I should not address it here in this manner.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

All five people log in using the same User account? In that case, there will be no reliable way to determine *which* person is logged in at any given time.

The only possible solution I can think of in this scenario is overly complex, but here goes:
You'd need to set up a custom VF page as the landing page of their default app or set up a Home Page Component, and in either case have it run logic/JavaScript to determine if the current user is the shared account, in which case a modal dialog pops up that requires them to select which person they are (maybe set up these people as Contact records that contain their Gmail addresses). This would then need to write to a field on the User record (either copying in that email, or possibly establishing a look-up to that contact). Your formula field would then be able to read from this User field. 
However, this is still not 100% reliable because you wouldn't have a way to automatically clear that custom field on User of the previous value, meaning you can't guarantee that it would hold the correct value at all times because there are ways that these people might unintentionally bypass hitting your person-selector...

Why not just give them separate accounts instead? It would be much simpler!

Comment: Thanks for your input @RenegadeCoder but I am sure that this can be managed with way simpler way. Trigger might do the job. Whenever a record is saved, automatically get their log in email address on that PC and place it in a field on that specific record. This is what i am thinking of but i am not sure if I can pull it off because I need someone from you guys as Salesforce guru to help me out :)

Comment: The problem is that SFDC would have no insight to the login they use on their PC, and by definition the user account will always have the same email regardless of who logs in.

I could almost see a different kludge solution involving session IP addresses, but that would be a huge mess and would require these people to always log in from specific static IPs...

Comment: i am not sure if that is right. Because all these users have their own email address and all of them are logging on their own PC. So this should get their Gmail address and not the login salesforce address.

Comment: I am sure that's right: Salesforce does not have any visibility into the user's PC (at least not without some major security risks and bad practices).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want Salesforce to automatically detect which of 5 users that are using the same SF User account Id to log-in from and enter their gmail email account address into a formula field. Salesforce can only detect the current User Id. You'll need to either have the users who are sharing the account enter their gmail email addresses into a text field that can then be processed into your formula field, or an easier method for them, would be to have a drop-down picklist that contained either their names or email addresses to choose from.

Once you had that, you could then take the values from the picklist and send them to your formula field as records are saved or updated.  As an FYI, a picklist's values are simply text fields and you wouldn't necessarily need to even have them stored in a custom object. They could be stored in a Custom Setting and their values changed as needed whenever employees leave or are hired. Maps will readily allow you to display names that will translate to email addresses.

You could presumably keep this in memory by setting the value of a Global Static Variable for the duration of the session to use whenever a record is saved or updated.

Comment: How would you keep it in memory? As far as i know, there's no way to persist a variable for the life of a session because Apex statics only hold values for the life of a single transaction.

Comment: A Global Static Variable should persist if I'm not mistaken, but I could be wrong. Hmmm, no, only if it were in a class that continued to run. An alternative option would be to write to a Custom Setting and call it from there.

Comment: No, the global modifier only enables out-of-namespace access, but has no effect on persistence. Even if it were in a class (such as a page controller), the static variable would lose its value and re-null after every user action (button/link click, page load, etc).
Using a custom setting might work, but that's effectively equivalent to my suggestion of a custom field on the User record.

Comment: I'm not certain that it would re-null. That would seem to depend on the method and how it was written (get only if Global Vars value = null, etc). I don't disagree that a custom setting is the equivalent of a custom field. The issue there is that it sounds as though only one User would need the custom field, thus the recommendation to use Custom Settings.

Comment: Thanks for your input @crmprogdev but I already have that picklist that contains names. What I want to achieve here is something more complex that even they won't know when they edit a record. I need this because in some cases if something gets messed up I will know who did what by that email address that was taken from the gmail without the effort from their side to pick from a picklist. I want this to be done upon saving of that record.